# Unable to execute java GUI program with Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, ubuntu

I am unable to execute java gui program in eclipse 3.6 under ubuntu 11.04. when i click on run as `Java Application` nothing happens. When i switched to `console` there just `<terminated>`

So what to do. I have installed `jdk 1.6.0_25`

Also there is an openjdk installed in my system. but i don't know how to configure this with eclipse.

Here is the program:

```
public class AnimWallpaper {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserInterface mainWindow = new UserInterface();
    }
}



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class UserInterface extends Frame {

    /**
     * Serial version Id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7925308422918335055L;
    public UserInterface(){
        setTitle("Animated Wallpaper");
        setSize(400, 300);

        Container con = new Container();

        con.setBackground(new Color(83, 68, 235));



        add(con);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void closingEvent(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Both classes are in different file and in same package com.anim

Thanks In advance:)

Comment: Hmm, we need some more info to troubleshoot this unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a main method creating a instance of a Frame?

Comment: start it from console and see for the log

Comment: did you set it (jframe) visible? `this.setVisible(true)`

Comment: I tried ./eclipse from console but no log appeared there

Comment: Okk sorrry. i thought i am having some problem related to environment. but this was my mistake. sorry to you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your window [visible](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) in order for it to show.
add the line `setVisible(true);`